# How to add a css class to custom field value?

Tags: custom-field, css

In the user's profile there is a dropdown list with options to choose from. The custom field name is colors with several values: red, green, blue, etc. Can I add a css class to those values. Like red_css, blue_css etc? To style accordinly. .blue_css {font-size: 10px;}

Is that even possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very similar to how you set / access theme options:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_option

setting:

`update_user_option( $user_id, $option_name, $newvalue, $global )` <- taken from wordpress codex.

and getting :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_option

`get_user_option('color_option', $userID);`

To get your specific request fulfilled, you would need to find the user_option(s) and then append to the list via a plugin or theme customization